# Memory leak in BSTR to wstring

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, com, bstr

Consider following code, Is there a memory leak in this?

```
HRESULT GetPath(wstring &outDomainPath)
{
    CComBSTR bstrDomainPath;

    AnotherGetPath(&bstrDomainPath);
    outDomainPath = bstrDomainPath.Detach();
}
```

What is the difference in this?( Still memory leak??)

```
HRESULT GetPath(wstring &outDomainPath)
{
    CComBSTR bstrDomainPath;

    AnotherGetPath(&bstrDomainPath);
    outDomainPath = bstrDomainPath;//removed detach
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CComBSTR` is a RAII wrapper around raw `BSTR` strings.

In the first code snippet you posted:

> ```
> outDomainPath = bstrDomainPath.Detach();
> ```

you invoke [`CComBSTR::Detach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ze9wff0.aspx), which **releases the ownership** of the wrapped `BSTR` string, and *transfers* this ownership to "someone else".
In your case, "someone else" is a `std::wstring` object (referenced by `outDomainPath`), which is *not* a RAII wrapper around `BSTR`s.

Now, consider that, from C++ type system perspective, a `BSTR` is basically a `wchar_t*`. Moreover, `std::wstring` implements constructor and assignment operator overloads that take `const wchar_t*` as input, assuming these raw `wchar_t` pointers are C-style NUL-terminated strings. So, you can create `std::wstring` objects from raw C-style strings.

The problem is that, when you invoke `CComBSTR::Detach`, the raw `BSTR` ownership is transferred to the caller, which is responsible to properly *release* the `BSTR` string.

But, in your case, you are creating a `wstring` object from the `wchar_t*` (`BSTR`) returned by `CComBSTR::Detach`, *"orphaning"* the returned `BSTR` string.

In fact, who will be responsible for properly releasing the `BSTR`, invoking [`SysFreeString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms221481(v=vs.85).aspx) on it? The `std::wstring` destructor won't do that.

So, in this case you leak the `BSTR` returned by `CComBSTR::Detach`.

---

On the other hand, in the second code snippet:

> ```
> outDomainPath = bstrDomainPath;//removed detach
> ```

what happens is that the compiler implicitly invokes [`CComBSTR::operator BSTR`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dbyydwx6.aspx), which basically gives the caller access to the `BSTR` wrapped inside `CComBSTR`. Note that in this case there is **no ownership transfer**: you are just *observing* the `BSTR`, that is still owned by the `CComBSTR` RAII wrapper.

`std::wstring` has constructor and op= overloads to create `wstring` objects from raw `const wchar_t*` NUL-terminated C-style strings. `BSTR` is basically a `wchar_t*` from C++ type system perspective, so if your `BSTR` contains a NUL-terminated string (*without* embedded NULs inside), that line of code will *duplicate* the `BSTR` string, copying it to a `std::wstring` object.

Then, at the end of your `GetPath` function, the local `CComBSTR bstrDomainPath` object will go out of scope, the `CComBSTR` destructor will be automatically invoked by the C++ compiler, and `SysFreeString` will be called to properly release the wrapped `BSTR`.

In this case, you have no `BSTR` leak.

Please note that this code works if you *don't* have embedded NULs in your `BSTR`. In case of embedded NULs, only the first *"substring"* will be copied, as the `wstring` constructor that takes a `const wchar_t*` as input will stop at the *first* NUL.

In addition, I encourage you to read this interesting blog post:

> [Eric Lippert's Guide to BSTR Semantics](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2003/09/12/erics-complete-guide-to-bstr-semantics/)

Comment: Excellent for mentioning that the naive conversion from `BSTR` to `wchar_t*` only works if you can guarantee that the source string does not have embedded null characters. Both `BSTR` and `wstring` can handle embedded nulls, but the intermediate `wchar_t*` cannot.